# error CS2001: Source file could not be found

Tags: .net, svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a .net application and configured the application in the Jenkins for the automation build. I have used SVN for the "Source Code Management". But when I build the application through the Jenkins then it shows the below error:

> CSC : error CS2001: Source file 'App_Start\FilterClass.cs' could not be found [F:\Pankaj\Projects\Jenkins Code\WorkSpace\MySolution.csproj]

And this issue is coming for multiple files. However, when I get the latest code from the SVN and build the project separably then it is working fine. But when I use Jenkins then those files are missing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to force checkout repo instead of using update in Jekins. In addition make sure that you have the correct version of msbuild plugin intalled for Jenkins. I had similar issues when correct dependencies were not installed for jenkins on a slave node.

I hope that these tips will help you.

Regards,
Yasir

Comment: Thanks Yasir. I have installed the MSBuild 1.26 version, and I hope this is the lasted version of MSBuild.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. Added the MVC reference to the project and committed the project file. Now whenever Jankins build the solution, it fetch the updated files from the SVN and build the project.

Reason: The system.web.mvc reference was missing in the project.